# I need to create a meta_key = full_name in mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress, meta-key

I am using WordPress, and in MySQL database i  have meta_values for `meta_key=first_name` and `meta_key=last_name`.

Now i want to create in MySQL database a `meta_key=full_name`

I have tried different ways but i haven't been successfull doing it. Any suggestion how i can solve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in this site. Always be specific and make your best effort before asking, and don't treat Stack Overflow as a repository of tutorials. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http:s//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions. Also you mention that you tried many ways you did include none. Why do you want to create a new meta_key? you can concatenate `first_name` and `last_name` using a simple query.

Comment: I have in the table values for `meta_key=first_name` and `meta_key='first_name' `

I need `meta_key=full_name`
I think there should be a better solution , bu i  tried to create it manually in MySQL but i was not able to give a query. 
`SELECT user_id,meta_key,meta_value
  FROM {$wpdb->usermeta} 
  WHERE ({$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = 'first_name' AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = 'last_name')";
 meta_key=full_name 
WHERE full_name='first_name'. 'last+name';`